# How do I get "perl Makefile.PL" to use all needed paths?

Tags: perl, makefile

I'm trying to compile and install a newer perl module for OpenSSL on Ubuntu 16.04:
(https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1017/perl-lwp-unable-connect-tls-1.2-url-fail-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure)

The newer OpenSSL seems to be installed correctly (the folders and files are created in ~/build/openssl).
Compiling the new SSLeay fails, because it can't find libssl.so.1.1:

```
beheer@system:~/.local/share/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.92-eimXJF$ sudo OPENSSL_PREFIX=~/build/openssl perl Makefile.PL

Do you want to run external tests?
These tests *will* *fail* if you do not have network connectivity. [n] y
*** Be sure to use the same compiler and options to compile your OpenSSL, perl,
    and Net::SSLeay. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported.
~/build/openssl/bin/openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Use of uninitialized value $output in scalar chomp at Makefile.PL line 398.
Use of uninitialized value $output in pattern match (m//) at Makefile.PL line 401.
Use of uninitialized value $output in pattern match (m//) at Makefile.PL line 404.
Use of uninitialized value $output in concatenation (.) or string at Makefile.PL line 413.

*** OpenSSL version test failed
    (`' has been returned)
    Either you have bogus OpenSSL or a new version has changed the version
    number format. Please inform the authors!
```

The requested libssl.so.1.1 is available on ~/build/openssl/lib

When using that path for OPENSSL_PREFIX, the headers aren't found:

```
sudo OPENSSL_PREFIX=~/build/openssl/lib perl Makefile.PL
Do you want to run external tests?
These tests *will* *fail* if you do not have network connectivity. [n] y
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: Guessing NAME [Net-SSLeay-1.92-eimXJF] from current directory name.
Warning: NAME must be a package name
*** Be sure to use the same compiler and options to compile your OpenSSL, perl,
    and Net::SSLeay. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported.   

******************************************************************************
* COULD NOT FIND LIBSSL HEADERS                                              *
*                                                                            *
* The libssl header files are required to build Net-SSLeay, but they are     *
* missing from ~/build-openssl/lib. They would typically reside              *
* in ~/build/openssl/lib/include/openssl.                                    *
*                                                                            *
* If you are using the version of OpenSSL/LibreSSL packaged by your Linux    *
* distribution, you may need to install the corresponding "development"      *
* package via your package manager (e.g. libssl-dev for OpenSSL on Debian    *
* and Ubuntu, or openssl-devel for OpenSSL on Red Hat Enterprise Linux and   *
* Fedora).                                                                   *
******************************************************************************
```

Adding the paths via arguments won't help:
`~/.local/share/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.92-eimXJF$ sudo OPENSSL_PREFIX=~/build/openssl perl Makefile.PL INC='-I~/build/openssl/lib -I~/build/openssl/include -I~/build/openssl/bin' LIBS='~/build/openssl/lib'`

This gives the same error:
`error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Note that *No such file or directory* could refer to libssl.so.1.1, but also to a library needed by libssl.so.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you've installed openssl (maybe you didn't?), but you shouldn't need the "lib" portion of the path. Here's what I have set and I don't have this problem. The examples in [Net::SSLeay](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.92/README)'s docs don't include the "lib" part either.

```
$ env | grep OPENSSL
OPENSSL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ssl

$ ls /usr/local/ssl
bin         include         man         openssl.cnf     private
certs
```

If you haven't completed the `make install` part, you aren't giving the library the chance to put everything in the right place.